# Issue in grouping by dates

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a list of timers like

```
timer 1 => { startDate = 17/01/2019 11PM, endDate = 18/01/2019 9AM } 
timer 2 => { startDate = 18/01/2019 7AM, endDate = 18/01/2019 1PM } 
timer 3 => { startDate = 18/01/2019 12PM, endDate = 18/01/2019 10PM } 
timer 4 => { startDate = 18/01/2019 11PM, endDate = 19/01/2019 9AM }
```

I need to group by the dates with this logic.

1. timer 1 starts at 17/01/2019 11PM and ends at next day. this timer should be grouped under 17/01/2019 (1 timer)
2. timer 2 and timer 3 resides in the 18/01/2019, this should be grouped under 18/01/2019 (2 timers)
3. timer 4 starts at 18 and ends at 19, which should be grouped under 19/01/201 (1 timer)

Code:

```
let sortedTimers = timers.sort((a, b) => {
     return a.startDate.isBefore(b.startDate) ? -1 : 1;
});        
let groupedByDate: { [date: string]: Timer[] } = _.groupBy(sortedTimers, timer => {
    let start = this.dateFormatter.toDayOfWeekLongDate(Timer.startDate);
    let end = this.dateFormatter.toDayOfWeekLongDate(Timer.endDate);
    return start == end? start:end; // wrong logic
});
```

This one returns only two groups 
1. 18/01/2019 (3 timers)
2. 19/01/201 (1 timer)
but I need three groups. I know the logic is wrong in the above code.

I'm using lodash for grouping. Any leads would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What's the logic that says that 17-18 should be grouped under 17 but 18-19 should be grouped under 19?  In other words, what about timer 4 makes it different from timer 1?

Comment: oh forgot to mention that, 18/01/2019 is the current date. we need to check which timer overlaps the current date, timer 1 starts yesterday but finishes today, timer 4 starts tonight and ends next day

Comment: To my mind that still doesn't describe the logic.  Is a timer that starts today grouped differently from the others?  Or is a timer that ends today grouped differently from the others?

Comment: Yes, if the timer starts today and ends today, it should be grouped with todays date. If the timer starts yeterday and ends today, should be grouped with yesterdays date, if the timer starts today and ends tomorrow, it should be grouped with tomorrows date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add current date in the condition as your logic takes into consideration the current date as well i.e. if(start == end) return start elseif(start < end & end==currDate) return start elseif(start < end & end>currDate) return end
Something to that effect.

Comment: Yes, I have done that, but just wanted to know whether it can be done with out comparing with the current date.

Comment: You described the logic (in a comment above) as having to do with comparisons to the current date.  It's hard to imagine how you could then solve the problem without doing such comparisons.